# How to use sort_by to sort alphabetically then numerically then by special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array:

```
arr = ["Bar", "abc", "foo", "1", "20”, "10", "_def"]
```

I need to sort using case-insensitive alphabetically first, then numerically followed by special characters.

I am trying to use `sort_by`:

```
irb(main):071:0> arr.sort_by {|s| [s[/[0-9a-z]+/], s.to_i]}
=> ["1", "10", "20", "abc", "Bar", "_def", "foo"]
```

The output has to be:

```
arr = ["abc", "Bar", "foo", "1", “10”, “20", "_def"]
```

Comment: In real life we should not have arrays with such wide-ranging values; We'd control what our input was. That makes me think this is a homework problem. "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#3C-3D-3E-method):

> Arrays are compared in an “element-wise” manner; the first element of `ary` is compared with the first one of `other_ary` using the `<=>` operator, then each of the second elements, etc…

You can take advantage of this behavior by creating sorting groups:

```
arr = ["Bar", "abc", "foo", "1", "20", "10", "_def"]

arr.sort_by do |s|
  case s
  when /^[a-z]/i
    [1, s.downcase]
  when /^\d/
    [2, s.to_i]
  else
    [3, s]
  end
end
#=> ["abc", "Bar", "foo", "1", "10", "20", "_def"]
```

The first element (`1`, `2`, `3`) defines the group's position: strings with letters on 1st position, numeric strings on 2nd position and the remaining on 3rd position. Within each group, the elements are sorted by the second element: strings with letters by their lowercase value, numeric strings by their integer value and the remaining by themselves.

Comment: Just realized that this is a variant of [demir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62622871/477037). Maybe it provides some additional information, though.

Comment: Nice solution Stefan.

Comment: It's not really a variant, it's an alternate approach. There are a limited number of ways to do some things so there will often be overlap. Personally, I find this more simple and easier to read, and it should be faster. Oh. I feel a benchmark coming on.

Comment: This does not correctly sort strings such as `'aa'` vs. `'a1'`, because you decide the "group" on the first character only. If I understood the OP correctly, he wants to have a "custom collating sequence" of the characters, where first are all the letters, then all the digits, finally everything else. ( @user3189916: Can you confirm this?).

Answer (score 4):

You can create groups first and then sort groups.

```
arr.each_with_object(Array.new(3) { Array.new }) do |word, group|
  if word.match /^[A-Za-z]/
    group.first
  elsif word.match /^[0-9]/
    group.second
  else
    group.third
  end << word
end.flat_map{ |group| group.sort_by{ |x| x.downcase } }

#=> ["abc", "Bar", "foo", "1", "10", "20", "_def"]
```

Comment: Is there any method name `second` and `third` for array? Which Ruby version are you using?

Comment: @Rajagopalan No, they're not ruby methods. I used these methods because the question has ruby-on-rails-5 tag. group[1] and group[2] can be used instead of these methods for plain ruby.

Comment: Ohhhh okay, thanks. I know group[1], group[2] can be used

Comment: Rather than hand out code, also explain how it works and why it's the appropriate solution. The goal is to educate, not just solve this immediate problem.

Answer (score 1):

A little benchmark is needed:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/array/access.rb'
require 'fruity'

ARR = ["Bar", "abc", "foo", "1", "20", "10", "_def"]

def run_demir(ary)
  ary.each_with_object(Array.new(3) { Array.new }) do |word, group|
    if word.match /^[A-Za-z]/
      group.first
    elsif word.match /^[0-9]/
      group.second
    else
      group.third
    end << word
  end.flat_map{ |group| group.sort_by{ |x| x.downcase } }
end

def run_stefan(ary)
  ary.sort_by do |s|
    case s
    when /^[a-z]/i
      [1, s.downcase]
    when /^\d/
      [2, s.to_i]
    else
      [3, s]
    end
  end
end

run_demir(ARR)  # => ["abc", "Bar", "foo", "1", "10", "20", "_def"]
run_stefan(ARR) # => ["abc", "Bar", "foo", "1", "10", "20", "_def"]

compare do
  demir  { run_demir(ARR)  }
  Stefan { run_stefan(ARR) }
end
```

Which results in:

```
# >> Running each test 512 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> Stefan is faster than demir by 2x ± 0.1
```